# How do I call a function inside a struct from that function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay, this is a basic outline of my code

```
exports.entity = {
    name:"Foo",
    //Etc...
    start:function() {
        this.attack();
    },
    attack:function() {
        setTimeout(attack, 1000); //Doesn't work
        setTimeout(this.attack, 1000); //Doesn't work
        setTimeout(this, 1000); //Doesn't work
    }
}
```

As you can probably see, I would like to call `attack()` from inside that function using a `setTimeout`. Unfortunately, everything I've tried doesn't work, and I'm running dry on ideas. I couldn't find anything on the internet. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Note:
When I say `doesn't work`, I mean that it gives me an error saying something like `(insert what I tried here, e.g. 'this.attack') is not a function`

Comment: `setTimeout(() => this.attack(), ...)` or `setTimeout(this.attack.bind(this), ...)`

Comment: or `attack: function attack() { setTimeout(attack, 1000); }`

Comment: Thanks Patrick Roberts, that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do to avoid problems of scope is to split the functions. And then export the object.

```
const attack = () => {
  console.log('attacking');
  setTimeout(() => {
    stop();
  }, 1000)
};

const stop = () => {
  console.log('stopping');
}

const start = () => {
  attack();
}

module.exports = { start, stop, attack }
```

Otherwise you can bind(this) as it was suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` has own scope that is why It is overriding this

You can use `bind` or take variable outside `setTimeout`

```
//using bind
setTimeout((function() {
    this.attack();
}).bind(this));

//using variable
 var context = this;
 setTimeout(context.attack, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can look like this:

```
let entity = {};
entity.name = "Foo";

// Etc...

entity.start = function() {
    this.attack();
}.bind(entity);

entity.attack = function() {
    console.log('attack');
    setTimeout(this.attack, 1000); //Doesn't work
}.bind(entity);

exports = { entity };
```